# I have a DVD stuck in my iMac, how do I get it out?

Tags: dvd, optical-drive, imac

I am asking this question on behalf of my sister.  Here's what she had to say on facebook:

> Anyone know how to get a DVD unstuck from an iMac drive? I tried
>   everything I read online--shutting down, holding mouse on reboot,
>   trash-dragging, waiting overnight for iMac's temper to cool, a fish
>   hook, a butter knife (ok, maybe not the last two, but I'm about ready
>   to). Please don't make me see a "Genius"! Please PLEASE no
>   "Geniuses"!!!... Waa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She found the answer.  Again, I shall quote her (the emphasis is mine):

> Finally went to the Geniuses today as a LAST resort to get my DVD
>   unstuck from my iMac. **Solution: shut down completely, turn back on and
>   hold the "eject" key down DURING start up until disc pops out! Worked
>   like a champ!**

Answer (score 2):

From [The ultimate guide to ejecting a stuck disc from Mac SuperDrive](http://www.macyourself.com/2009/05/01/the-ultimate-guide-to-ejecting-a-stuck-disc-from-mac-superdrive/)

> **Disk Utility**
>   Launch Disk Utility (Applications > Utilities) and select the troublesome CD or DVD in the sidebar. Click the Eject button at the top of the window.
>
> **Terminal command**
>   Launch Terminal (Applications > Utilities) and copy the following command: `drutil eject`
>
> **Mouse/Trackpad button**
>   Restart your Mac and hold down the left mouse button (or trackpad if you have a laptop) as it boots up. Keep pressing it until the login screen or desktop displays.
>
> **Tilt and shake**
>   Pick up your Mac laptop and tilt it so the CD/DVD drive is pointing downwards. Restart and hold the Eject key down while gently shaking the computer up and down.
>
> **The self-fixing Mac**
>   Shut down your Mac, turn it back on, and let it sit for 10-15 minutes. Make sure the power cord is plugged in as you do this and the disc just might pop out on its own.
>
> **Disrupt the spin**
>   If you listen carefully, you can probably hear your optical drive powering up & down over and over again. As long as the disc spins, it’s not coming out. The first step is to get your hands on a very thin piece of cardboard or even a folded business card (so it’s twice as thick). Now restart your Mac and hold down the mouse/trackpad button as you poke the cardboard inside the SuperDrive slot. The goal is to slip it above the CD or DVD — towards the left side of the drive — and gently jiggle it around to put pressure on the disc. You might have to continue this for up to a minute or so, but it often works when all other methods fail.

Tilt-and-shake probably isn't a good idea with an iMac and you've tried holding the mouse button on reboot, but the rest seem worth a shot.